# Characteristic function of sum of exponentials

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be i.i.d. random variables, $X_i \sim \exp(\frac{1}{i!})$.
I want to compute the limit of the characteristic function of $\frac{S_n}{n!} = \frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n!}$.
By using the properties of the characteristic function, I have:
$$\varphi_{S_n/n!}(t) = \frac{1}{1-\frac{it}{n!}} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{it\cdot (n-1)!}{n!}} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{it\cdot n!}{n!}}$$
Is it rigorous to say that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi_{S_n/n!}(t) = \frac{1}{1-it}$ since we have $$\varphi_{S_n/n!}(t) = \underbrace{\frac{1}{1-\frac{it}{n!}} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{it}{n}}}_{\to \, 1 \text{ as } n \to \infty} \cdot \frac{1}{1-it} ?$$

My problem is that the number of the factors increases as $n$ grows. So, in the end I am dealing with an infinite product and I am afraid that some more robust argument is needed.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to compute $S_n/n!$ and not the average $S_n/n$?

Comment: @Gregory I want to prove that $S_n/n! \to \exp(1)$ in law. It is just the text of the exercise.

Comment: I think you need to show why the infinite product converges. One idea would be to write the product $P_N = \prod_{n=1}^N \left(1 - \frac{it n!}{N!} \right)^{-1}$ and take the natural log $\ln P_N = -\sum_{n=1}^N \ln \left(1 - \frac{it n!}{N!} \right)$ and try to show that this sum converges (you may need to use the principal branch of the log function here).